# Permission denied when running shell script using 'wkhtmltopdf' tool

Tags: bash, shell, wkhtmltopdf, permission-denied

**Hi!**
So, I am using the [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) tool in a **script** on my Ubuntu terminal...

```
#!/bin/bash
#search for every '*.html' extension and store it in 'output.txt' file 
find /home/guidine/09 -name '*.html' > output.txt
#read 'output.txt' file executing the command 'wkhtmltopdf' syntax for each line
for word in $(cat /home/guidine/bin/output.txt)
do 
    $wkhtmltopfd $word $word".pdf"
done
```

Which returns every line (it's a path) in the 'output.txt' with the 'Permission denied' message (example annexed), *can anyone help me?*

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FFHW.jpg)

I've already did `$ chmod +x wkhtmltopdf.sh`.

I've found an alternative that satisfied me and I'm closing the question.

```
find <directory> -name '*.html' -exec wkhtmltopdf {} {}.pdf \;
```

Comment: what is the value of `$wkhtmltopfd` ?